# custom dropdown with parent having overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

As far as I can see, building a custom select box is somehow problematic on web clients. It basically boils down to 2 options at high level:

1. Append the options dropdown to the element itself. In this case, if a parent of the select box has `overflow: hidden`, dropdown will be clipped if it overflows.
2. Append the options dropdown to body, in this case, parents having `overflow: hidden` won't be a problem, but we'd need to track multiple events that could change the position/size of the select element (scrolling, this could be any parent element of the select box, resizing, select element getting hidden inside a scrollable element etc.), and this seems both difficult to manage and as many things need to be tracked real time, can cause performance issues.

My question is, with the latest state of html / css / javascript supported by browsers, is there a new way to handle these problems, that weren't available before? Or maybe there is another option than the ones I pointed out above.

[Fiddle explaining the two cases](https://jsfiddle.net/2um1yv67/)

Comment: When you say custom select box do you mean custom styling/animation for a `select` element or do you mean making a select box with elements that are not `select`?

Comment: I mean the latter, but as far as I know, custom styling options for a select element is limited

Comment: Why would the select changing size be a problem? That's what base `<select>` elements do as well if you don't constrain the width. I use `<ul>` lists positioned relative or absolute to their parent, with overflow-y scroll and with a z-index, so they overlap their siblings and parent when opened. Which usually gives me more than half the screen size to play with. If an option in a select needs more room than half the screen size there's too much text inside the option.

Comment: @Shilly it is not necessarily half the screen. Consider placing the select in a parent with small height having overflow hidden

Comment: I still don't understand the exact issue. The page can scroll independent from the select. And position absolute will still overflow the parent if the fake select contains more options than the parent height can contain, even with overflow hidden. And it will retain it's position relative to the parent when the screen resizes, unless you use like pixels instead of relative units; percentages, rem or vh; to define the position. Could you please show some simple HTML/CSS showing your concerns? Since there very well might be new ways to handle this problem.

Comment: @Shilly here's a very basic fiddle displaying the two options I mentioned above: https://jsfiddle.net/2um1yv67/ . In the first you can see the options scroll with the select but clipped when overlows, and the second is not clipped but does not move with the element when it scrolls, unless I add extra code to make the options move with select

Answer (score 0):

Basic example of what I mean.

There's more options that we have room on the screen so the 
fake select will overflow its parent and also the bottom of the screen.

Could you check what is missing here to fix your issue?

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector( '.select' );
const selected = document.querySelector( '.selected' );
const default_text = '... Select options ...';
dropdown.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  const classes = event.target.classList;
  if ( classes.contains( 'option' )) {
    // clicked first element
    // open the dropdown.
    // update the label if needed.
    if ( classes.contains( 'selected' )) {
      dropdown.classList.toggle( 'active' );
      if ( selected.innerHTML !== default_text ) selected.innerHTML = default_text;
    }
    // clicked other element
    // close the dropdown
    // update the label
    else {
      dropdown.classList.remove( 'active' );
      selected.innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.select {
  list-style: none;
  height: 22px; /* 20px + 2px borders */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.select.active {
  overflow: visible;
}
.option {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  height: 20px;
}
.selected {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
label,
input {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" value="">
  <ul class="select">
    <li class="option selected">... Select options ...</li>
    <li class="option">1</li>
    <li class="option">2</li>
    <li class="option">3</li>
    <li class="option">4</li>
    <li class="option">5</li>
    <li class="option">6</li>
    <li class="option">7</li>
    <li class="option">8</li>
    <li class="option">9</li>
    <li class="option">10</li>
    <li class="option">11</li>
    <li class="option">12</li>
    <li class="option">13</li>
    <li class="option">14</li>
    <li class="option">15</li>
    <li class="option">16</li>
    <li class="option">17</li>
    <li class="option">18</li>
    <li class="option">19</li>
    <li class="option">20</li>
    <li class="option">21</li>
    <li class="option">22</li>
    <li class="option">23</li>
    <li class="option">24</li>
    <li class="option">25</li>
  </ul>
  <label>Value:</label>
  <input type="text" value="">
</section>
```

Comment: Problem arises if you add "overflow: hidden" style to "container" class

Comment: What would be the point of doing that when you actually want the container to overflow? But that's easily fixed by changing the position relative to position absolute on the `.select` class if for some reason it's needed. ( updated the code to reflect this )

Comment: I think that the reason it did not work that way in your fiddle is because you only absolutely position the options, not the entire `select-element`.

Comment: I think its related to options being positioned relative to select box in my example, as when you set position: absolute, the item is position relative to the closest absolute or relative position element. In your example now it works, but if you add position: relative to container, it will start to get clipped again, as the select will be positioned relative to the container

Comment: My general point is, you do not have control over where developers will use your select element. Even if you do it your way, it could well be placed inside an absolutely positioned overflow hidden element, and you can not guarantee it will not be clipped unless you append the options to body (or use static positioning for options). And when you place it so, you need to track several events to keep options in sync with where the actual select box is

Comment: Can't seem to figure something out directly for this specific case, so I'm giving up. I've never had to deal with this issue again since I started using grid. It's always the children positioned absolute to a relative parent which is positioned using grid. Since grid fixes the issues which in the past were only possible with positioning or floating, I no longer have to use the `position: x` on parents anymore. This leaves `position: absolute` available to any child element to pop out of the parent layout ( and hence out of `overflow: hidden`.